# Java: Generate Unique Random Character

Tags: java, random, character

I have a string of "random" characters. I assigned a numeric value to each character depending on its position in the string and then set a loop to output the character at whatever random position gets chosen. Here's my code so far:

```
public class Random9_4 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String chords = "ADE";
    final int N = chords.length();
    java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        //char s = chords.charAt(rand.nextInt(N));
        //char t = chords.charAt(rand.nextInt(N));

        System.out.println(chords.charAt(rand.nextInt(N)));
        //temp variable
        //while(s == t)
        //{
        //  
        //}System.out.println(chords.charAt(rand.nextInt(N)));
    }
  }
}
```

As of now it works fine but the characters can repeat at times. I want it so that it is "unique" output of characters (meaning the subsequent character does not repeat). I understand one way to do this is to use a temporary variable to check the current character with the previous one and the character that will be displayed next but I am unsure of how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an inner loop to generate a new character if it matches with the character generated in the last iteration.

The `temp` is a temporary character variable which remembers the last character generated. So in the `while` loop, we will iterate until a new character has been generated which is not the same as the character in the `temp` variable.

If a new character is generated, it will be assigned to the `temp` variable, so on the next iteration the same logic can be applied.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String chords = "ADE";
        final int N = chords.length();
        Random rand = new Random();
        char temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
           char s = chords.charAt(rand.nextInt(N));
           while(s == temp){ //loop until a new character is generated, this loop will stop when s != temp
               s = chords.charAt(rand.nextInt(N));
           }
           temp = s; //assign current character to the temp variable, so on next iteration this can be compared with the new character generated.
           System.out.println(s);
        }
}
```

Comment: This will get rid of any repeating characters but I wanted it to be looped, which is why I had it within the loop. I am unfamiliar with your method so I'm unsure of how to get it to repeat.

Comment: Apologies, I did not see it. Is there some sort of library I need to import for this? I get an error when I run it:  `Set cannot be resolved to a type                Hashset cannot be resolved to a ty                                                                     s cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: You need to import `import java.util.Set;` and `import java.util.HashSet;`

Comment: Okay that got rid of the errors, thank you. It only repeats for the size of the String though.

Comment: lets continue the discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188917/room-for-amardeep-bhowmick-and-joao-pedro)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly.

Does it just create a variable to store the previous output? Like the bleow code.

```
    final String chords = "ADE";
    final int N = chords.length();
    Random rand = new Random();
    Character curr = null;
    Character prev = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        curr = chords.charAt(rand.nextInt(N));
        while (curr == prev)
            curr = chords.charAt(rand.nextInt(N));

        prev = curr;
        System.out.println(curr);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Could you specify what part of my question you don't understand? Also, I tried your solution but I got an error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from null to char`  I'm not sure why but it won't let me set char to null

Comment: Oh. Have to change char to Character or specify char curr = prev = 0